# Compress If Conditions

Tags: javascript

Is there such a way to compress a block of conditions in an `if` statement?
As you can see from the code, `itemKey` is a variable. I set the first letter to be lowercased so I can match it to another variable `letter`.  The below works perfectly, but I would like to clean it up. Can I somehow pull all the `||` after the `&&` together to encompass all number 0-9? This is acting as a `string`, not `integer`.

```
firstLetterLower = itemKey.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
if(firstLetterLower==letter || (
   letter=='number' && (
      firstLetterLower=='0' || firstLetterLower=='1' || firstLetterLower=='2' || 
      firstLetterLower=='3' || firstLetterLower=='4' || firstLetterLower=='5' || 
      firstLetterLower=='6' || firstLetterLower=='7' || firstLetterLower=='8' || 
      firstLetterLower=='9'
   ))) {
```

Comment: Have you considered a regex?

Comment: `(firstLetterLower >= '0' && firstLetterLower <= '9')` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regex, you can do:

```
firstLetterLower = itemKey.charAt(0).toLowerCase();

if(firstLetterLower == letter || firstLetterLower.match(/^[0-9]$/) ){
}
```

This will check for your specified `letter` as well as match between 0 and 9.

However, if you don't want to use regex (overhead perhaps? Not that it would be noticeable here with 1 very simple regex), you can do as follows:

```
firstLetterLower = itemKey.charAt(0).toLowerCase();

if(firstLetterLower == letter || (firstLetterLower >= 0 && firstLetterLower <= 9)){
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can replace those tests with

```
firstLetterLower.match(/[0-9]/)
```

or

```
( firstLetterLower>=0 && firstLetterLower<=9 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex:

```
firstLetterLower.match(/^[0-9]/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of regex and what you have.  I would probably put it into a function:

```
function isMatch(itemKey, letter) {
    firstLetterLower = itemKey.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    if (firstLetterLower == letter) return true;

    if (letter == 'number'){
       if (firstLetterLower.match(/[0-9]/))
         return true;
        }
     return false;
}


alert("1:" + isMatch('item', 'i'));
alert("2:" +isMatch('1234567', 'number'));
alert("3:" +isMatch('abc','number'));
alert("4:" +isMatch('123','a'));
```